# JQuery button works on click but not working on Enter

Tags: jquery, html

I have a button as follows:

```
<input type="submit" value="click me" id="clickme" />
```

I want the button to perform action on **click and enter** (keyboard stroke).

Check my fiddle: **[`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/santhucool007/L6fhaz08/)**

It works on click but does not work on enter.

**CODE WITH SNIPPET PROVIDED BELOW**

```js
$('#clickme').keypress(function(e){
    if (e.which == 13){ //Enter key pressed
        alert('Enter pressed: Submitting the form....');
    }
});

$('#clickme').click(function(e){
    alert("clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" value="click me" id="clickme" />
```

Comment: The button must be on focus before pressing `Enter` for the `keypress` event to triggered...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#clickme').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.which == 13){//Enter key pressed
            alert('Enter pressed: Submitting the form....');
        }
    });

$('#clickme').click(function(e){
alert("clicked");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It works fine, but the button needs to be focused when pressing Enter.

For example click it first then press enter.

It seems the button is part of a form.

If you want to fire an event when submitting a form you should use:

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(){
});
```

If you really just want the button / form to work on enter anywhere in the website do:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
    $('#form').submit();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The keypress event for button is only going to occur when it is focused. and that happens on click of button only. You need to bind the keypress event on document itself or on submit event of form to make this work:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
 if(e.which == 13) {
    alert('Enter pressed: Submitting the form....');
}});
```

In case of form submission, you do not need to have two separate events. form submit event will handle both enter keypress and click of submit:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  alert('Enter pressed: Submitting the form....');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gzg323kv/)**

**Code Of Demo With Snippet Given Below**

```js
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
if(e.which == 13) {
    alert('Enter pressed: Submitting the form....');
}
});

$('#clickme').click(function(e){
alert("clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" value="click me" id="clickme" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the JQuery `submit` function, like so:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function () {
    alert("Submitted");
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rcwusdgx/1/)

Note: For your original code, the button must be on focus for the `keypress` event for `Enter` to be triggered